# Using hibernate HQL function elements

Tags: hibernate, hql, element

I'm trying to write HQL query to select `Player` with list of `Score` have only scores smaller than 3.
So relationship between `Player` and `Score` entities is one-to-many.
Sample hibernate mapping (mine):

```
<class table="player" name="Player">
    <id type="long" column="id" name="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

    <property name="name" type="string"/>

    <list name="scores" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
        <key column="score_id"/>
        <index column="table_row_num"/>
        <one-to-many class="Score"/>
    </list>
</class>

<class table="score" name="Score">
    <id type="long" column="id" name="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

    <property name="date" type="timestamp"/>
    <property name="score" type="int"/>
</class>
```

This sample is used in [hibernate manual](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) (as I understand entities relationship):

```
FROM Player p WHERE 3 > ALL ELEMENTS(p.scores)
```

And another my edition of this HQL:

```
FROM Player p JOIN p.scores s WHERE 3 > ALL ELEMENTS(s.score)
```

Another representive example from this manual that I try to understand:

```
SELECT p FROM NameList list, Person p WHERE p.name = SOME ELEMENTS(list.names)
```

SQL that I get:

```
select player0_.id as id0_, player0_.name as name0_ 
  from player player0_ 
 where 3 > all (select scores1_.id 
                  from score scores1_ 
                 where player0_.id=scores1_.score_id)
```

Note that selected field in the subquery is always `Score` identity...

Full [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is [here](http://sibsano.ru/files/hibernate-hql-elements.zip).

Is it possible to make the test work? Please help.

ps. Workarounds are not useful for me... I'm trying to understand scenarios when the `elements` function should to be used or perhaps if this is a hibernate bug (?)...

Comment: the fact you use `3 > ` for `greater than 3` is a typo ?